# How do i capture all csgo skins image url's in a row from a-z to a .csv or .sql file?

Tags: php, sql, csv, steam, steam-web-api

I was wondernig how i could capture all csgo skins image url's in a row from a-z to a .csv or .sql file. I've been trying to google it and try it myself for 2 days now without any success. When I say all csgo skins i'm talking about the ones on the market and who are over 400$. I've seen sites like http://csgo.steamanalyst.com and http://skins.csgodb.net/ and haven't figured it out yet. So what I'm asking for is how I can get list of all csgo skins image url's in ASC row (a-z) to html, csv or sql file.

Comment: [Start reading](http://steamcommunity.com/dev)

Answer (score 0):

Try to find API call (with auth of website owner) or look the API Steam (market not have api).

You can use PHP CURL to get webpage, find the url in source (with few ereg) to the image you want and download it (or store the link and save space).